# Does the Linux system lock the file when I copy it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have wrote a program and it will update a file periodically, sometimes I want to copy the file into another computer to check its content. If I copied the file when the program was not writing it, there is no problem. But, if I copied the file when the program was writing it, the copied file would be partial. So, I wonder that, if the Linux system exists the lock strategy to prevent the situation.

In fact, I copy the file in a bash script, so I want to check if the program is writing it in the bash script. If yes, the bash script will check its state after some seconds and then copy its completed version. So in bash script, how could we check the file was opened or modified by other programs?

Comment: No, Linux doesn't automatically lock files. If you want file locking, you have to do it explicitly in your application.

Comment: You can use the `flock(2)` system call in a C program to set/remove a lock, and the `flock(1)` command in a shell script to wait for the lock.

Comment: You could use a temporary file to do your update (mktemp), and when the file is completely updated, move/replace the original one.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, thank you very much for replying, and that's a very good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check from your script whether the file is being written to, and abort/pause copy if it is...

```
fuser -v /path/to/your/file | awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}$38=="F"{num++}END{print num}'
```

If the output is smaller 1 you're good to copy :)

Comment: thank you very much for replying! In `Ubuntu 12.04`, the command could output the processes that have been attaching to the file. But In `CentOS 5.7`, it says `fuser: command not found`, I think the `PATH` is not valid. And I also want to set the result of your command to one variable in the bash script, so we can use `while` to check the file's state.

Comment: In centos check whether psmisc is installed; if it is you may have to add /sbin to your PATH.  The script DOES return one value, so checking it in a loop should be no problem.

Comment: Yes! `/sbin/fuser` is valid!

Comment: Unless you're running as root, I don't think this will work if the file is open by another user. Also, the other process could start writing the file between the time that `fuser` finishes and when your script does the copy.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you very much for this useful suggestions! Currently I mainly use the system with one user and the files I copied are generated by the only user, so in current circumstance, the answer of tink is suitable. Thank you for indicating the minor flaw which may be useful for other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

When your code writes into the file, it actually writes into an output buffer in memory.  The buffer will be flushed out to disk when it becomes full.  Thus, when you copy the file whose buffer has not been flushed out to disk, you will observe partial file.

You can modify the buffer size by using the call to `setvbuf`.  If you set the buffer size to zero, it will get flushed out as it is written.  Another thing you can do is to make a call to `fflush()` to flush the output to disk.  Either of these two should update the file as it is written.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The copying script could still run between two calls to `printf()`, so it won't see everything that's being written.

Comment: Yes, but it will have everything that has been written into the file up to that point.

Comment: So? That may still be incomplete. If the writer is writing 100 things, you might copy it with only 50 of them.

Comment: As I read it, the OP periodically writes the file.  So, there may be a while between successive writes and he wants to see what has been written so far.  With disabled buffering, the file will reflect exactly what has been written and no wait for the buffer to be full.

Comment: @unxnut, thank you very much for replying! But I think your answer may be complex and tink's answer is easier.